# Joomla problem with MVC component

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I have problem with Joomla layouts in my component..There must be something bad with file/class name convention..
I was trying to ask on Joomla developer forum, but noone answered..
So I am getting this error..  500 - View not found [name, type, prefix]: PostToBank,,postToBankView
The view is in views/postTobank/view.php and name is postToBankViewPostToBank
In my controllers/controller.php file I have class named PaymentController which contains this part of code.

```
$view = $this->getView('PostToBank','','postToBankView');
        $this->getModel("Payment")->savePaymentData($data);
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $view->assignRef($key, $value);
        }
        $view->setLayout('postTobank');
        $view->display();
```

my view.php file looks like this

```
class postToBankViewPostToBank extends JView{
function display($tpl=null){


    //display set template

    parent::display($tpl);
}
```

}
on attached image is full folder structure of my component..
Please whats wrong with this?Thanks

[image: Folder structure of my compononent]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla uses a naming conventions and you are not following them. Refer to http://docs.joomla.org/File_Structure_and_Naming_Conventions

Also, your views should be `view.html.php` and then you do not need to call `setView`. 
FYI: this is where the error is coming from. Refer to this: http://docs.joomla.org/API16:JController/getView, even though it is 1.6 doc it is same in 1.5

Look though this tutorial and adopt regular conventions: http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1

Comment: the last link is exactly where from I was learning:)the folder structure seems to be exactly the same as in my component..
but as I am reading the article from first link now, I see there is much different folder structure..(in case of controllers)